# ORACLE: INSERT INTO Table VALUES of object type collection

Tags: oracle, collections, insert, forall

Having created the below types;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TYPE AS OBJECT
  ( FLAG      DATE
  , NUMB      NUMBER(2,0)
  , VARC      VARCHAR2(40 BYTE));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_OBJ_TYPE AS TABLE OF OBJ_TYPE;
/
```

I want to simply insert the data set into a table;

```
DECLARE
  DATA_SET TBL_OBJ_TYPE := TBL_OBJ_TYPE();
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM TBL_01)
  LOOP
    DATA_SET.EXTEND;
    DATA_SET(DATA_SET.COUNT) :=
    OBJ_TYPE( 1
            , REC.TBL_01_COL1
            , REC.TBL_01_COL2);
  END LOOP;

  FORALL REC IN DATA_SET.FIRST..DATA_SET.LAST
    INSERT INTO TBL_02 
    VALUES ( DATA_SET(REC).FLAG --listed column
           , DATA_SET(REC).NUMB --listed column
           , DATA_SET(REC).VARC); --listed column
END;
```

This one works fine, but is it somehow possible to change the "VALUES" clause to avoid naming each attribute in the source object? I would like something like this:

```
VALUES DATA_SET(REC)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can create tables using object type definitions:

```
SQL> create table TBL_02 of OBJ_TYPE
  2  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

There aren't many good reasons to do this, but we can work with the types in our programs.

Here is a little example, starting with the test data

```
SQL> select * from tbl_01
  2  /

     COL_1 COL_2
---------- ----------------------------------------
        23 ABC
        42 XYZ

SQL> DECLARE
  2     DATA_SET TBL_OBJ_TYPE := TBL_OBJ_TYPE();
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM TBL_01)
  5     LOOP
  6      DATA_SET.EXTEND;
  7      DATA_SET(DATA_SET.COUNT) :=
  8      OBJ_TYPE( sysdate
  9              , REC.COL_1
 10               , REC.COL_2);
 11     END LOOP;
 12
 13      FORALL REC IN DATA_SET.FIRST..DATA_SET.LAST
 14        INSERT INTO TBL_02 
 15        VALUES DATA_SET(REC)
 16        ; 
 17  END;
 18  /    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tbl_02;

FLAG            NUMB VARC
--------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
20-MAR-16         23 ABC
20-MAR-16         42 XYZ

SQL>
```

Alternatively we can use a PL/SQL object defined against the target table.  This uses a regular heap table for TBL_02:

```
DECLARE
  type tgt_nt is table of TBL_02%rowtype;
  data_set tgt_nt;
BEGIN
  SELECT sysdate, COL_1, COL_2 
  bulk collect into data_set
  FROM TBL_01;

  FORALL REC IN DATA_SET.FIRST..DATA_SET.LAST
    INSERT INTO TBL_02 
    VALUES DATA_SET(REC)
    ; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that columns in the table `TBL_01` have the same names as names in the object declaration:

```
DECLARE
  DATA_SET TBL_OBJ_TYPE := TBL_OBJ_TYPE();
BEGIN
    SELECT OBJ_TYPE( sysdate, numb, varc )  BULK COLLECT INTO  DATA_SET
    FROM TBL_01;

    INSERT INTO TBL_02( flag, numb, varc )
    SELECT * FROM Table( DATA_SET );
END;
/
```

If `TBL_01` columns have different names, say X,Y,Z, then change respectively this line: 
`SELECT OBJ_TYPE( X, Y, Z )  BULK COLLECT ...`

---

Note: you cannot assign `1` into the first field here:

```
OBJ_TYPE( 1
        , REC.TBL_01_COL1
        , REC.TBL_01_COL2);
```

because the first field `FLAG` is declared as of type `date` in the object declaration.
I've replaced `1` with `sysdate` in my example.

Comment: Hi kordirko, you're obviously right on the sysdate, just forgot to change. But anyway, is there some way to follow what I've mentioned; FORALL + INSERT INTO table VALUES --> with collection without specifying each column name, instead of using the SELECT clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
--Rollbaclk--

DROP TYPE TBL_OBJ_TYPE;
DROP TYPE OBJ_TYPE;
DROP TABLE TBL_02;
DROP TABLE TBL_01;

--execute--

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
   FLAG DATE,
   NUMB NUMBER (2, 0),
   VARC VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_OBJ_TYPE AS TABLE OF OBJ_TYPE;
/

CREATE TABLE TBL_02
(
   FLAG   DATE,
   NUMB   NUMBER (2, 0),
   VARC   VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE)
);


CREATE TABLE TBL_01
(
   TBL_01_COL0   DATE,
   TBL_01_COL1   NUMBER (2, 0),
   TBL_01_COL2   VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE)
);


INSERT INTO TBL_01
     VALUES (SYSDATE, 1, 'mohit');


INSERT INTO TBL_01
     VALUES (SYSDATE, 2, 'vijay');


INSERT INTO TBL_01
     VALUES (SYSDATE, 3, 'sohan');

COMMIT;


SELECT * FROM TBL_01;


DECLARE
   DATA_SET   TBL_OBJ_TYPE := TBL_OBJ_TYPE ();
BEGIN
   FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM TBL_01)
   LOOP
      DATA_SET.EXTEND;
      DATA_SET (DATA_SET.COUNT) :=
         OBJ_TYPE (REC.TBL_01_COL0, REC.TBL_01_COL1, REC.TBL_01_COL2);
   END LOOP;

   FORALL REC IN DATA_SET.FIRST .. DATA_SET.LAST
      INSERT INTO TBL_02
              VALUES (
                        DATA_SET (REC).FLAG,
                        DATA_SET (REC).NUMB,
                        DATA_SET (REC).VARC);
END;

SELECT * FROM TBL_02;
```