# How to use a defined record in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

To create a complex object I can use `CREATE TYPE`. However, how would I go through the entire flow in a valid way to insert and then retrieve a row with a custom type column? For eample:

```
-- 1. create type
CREATE TYPE address IS OBJECT
(
    street VARCHAR,
    city VARCHAR
);

-- 2. create table with that type
CREATE TABLE places (
    id INTEGER,
    address person
);

-- 3. insert a record
insert into places (1, ('victory', 'new york'));

-- 4. retrieve a record
select id, address.street from employees
```

Comment: it isn't that easy see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112518/oracle-insert-into-table-values-of-object-type-collection

Comment: @nbk oh wow. Are those used a lot in Oracle dbs. Or are they mainly put into separate tables and discouraged?

Comment: You and oracle try to make something that isn't  "normal" in SQL and oracle has it programmed that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way: define the length of `VARCHAR2`:

1. Create type

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TP_ADDRESS IS OBJECT
(
    STREET VARCHAR(50),
    CITY VARCHAR(50)
)
--  Result:     TYPE TP_ADDRESS compiled
```

Just added the name column....

2. Create table with that type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PLACES
(
    ID NUMBER(3),
    A_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    ADDRESS TP_ADDRESS
)
--  Result:     table PLACES created.
```

Referencing the type TP_ADDRESS(STREET, CITY)

3. Insert a record:

```sql
INSERT INTO PLACES (ID, A_NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES(1, 'JOHN DOE', TP_ADDRESS('Victory', 'New York'));

--  Result:     1 rows inserted.
```

Getting the value (table.column.type_element_name)

4. Retrieve record:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    A_NAME, 
    p.ADDRESS.STREET "STREET", 
    p.ADDRESS.CITY "CITY"
FROM 
    PLACES p;
--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--          ID  A_NAME                        STREET                                             CITY                                             
--  ---------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
--           1 JOHN DOE                       Victory                                            New York                                         
~~~
Regards...
```

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for your help. Your editings make the answer way better,  obviously. Regards...